# How is block scope managed in the lexical environment?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I declare a variable in a function using `var` then a slot for that variable is added to the `LexicalEnvironment` defined by that function.

```
function() {
  var foo; 
}
```

In the above code the `LexicalEnvironment` associated with the function contains a slot with a key `foo` and a value of `undefined`.

If I use a block-scoped declaration, how is the surrounding `LexicalEnvironment` affected?

```
function() {
  {
    let foo; // How does this affect the LexicalEnvironment?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function() {
  var foo; 
}
```

As you mentioned, `foo` is available in the `LexicalEnvironment` is global to all inner functions within that function.

But

```
function() {
  {
    let foo; // How does this affect the LexicalEnviroinment?
  }
}
```

Here `foo` is local to that block alone. It won't be visible outside that block.

How does it affect the `LexicalEnvironment` ?

If you are referencing, `foo` anywhere inside that block, the local `let foo` will override the global `var foo` which you've defined in that function.

> With respect to ES6,

```
function example(x) {
    console.log(y); // ReferenceError: y is not defined
    if (x) {
        let y = 5;
    }
}
```

Variables declared with a `let` statement are created as bindings on the lexical environment, rather than the variable environment, of the current execution context. A change to the specification of block statements in ES6 means that each block has its own lexical environment. In the above example, a new lexical environment is created when the block (the body of the if statement) is evaluated. When the let statement is evaluated a binding is added to this lexical environment and is innaccessible from the outer lexical environment (that of the function declaration itself).

**[Refer](http://globaldev.co.uk/2013/09/es6-part-2/)**

Comment: So,  in ES6, blocks can introduce new `LexicalEnvironment`s? Or is there a change so that a `LexicalEnvironment` can have more than one `[[Scope]]`?

Comment: `LexicalEnvironment` will have more than one `[[scope]]` based on the context.

Comment: ...which is a change from ES5?

Comment: Sorry, each block has its own lexical environment in ES6. Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Questions like this are best be answered by looking at the [spec](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-block):

> *Block* : { *StatementList* }
>
> 1. Let *oldEnv* be the [running execution context’s](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-execution-contexts) [LexicalEnvironment](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-lexical-environments).
> 2. Let *blockEnv* be [NewDeclarativeEnvironment](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-newdeclarativeenvironment)(*oldEnv*).
> 3. Perform [BlockDeclarationInstantiation](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-blockdeclarationinstantiation)(*StatementList*, *blockEnv*).
> 4. Set the [running execution context’s](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-execution-contexts) [LexicalEnvironment](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-lexical-environments) to *blockEnv*.
> 5. Let *blockValue* be the result of evaluating *StatementList*.
> 6. Set the [running execution context’s](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-execution-contexts) [LexicalEnvironment](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-lexical-environments) to *oldEnv*.
> 7. Return *blockValue*.
>
> NOTE: No matter how control leaves the Block the LexicalEnvironment is always restored to its former state.

So what happens here?

When the block is evaluated, a new lexical environment is created, with the current lexical environment as "parent". The new environment replaces the current environment for the duration of evaluating the block.

> If I use a block-scoped declaration, how is the surrounding `LexicalEnvironment` affected?

Other than it is temporarily replaced, it is not affected at all.

Comment: Hi @Felix Kling YOU ARE A GREAT REFERENCE in JavaScript, excellent answer, but I still have a doubt. is the lexical environment created ONLY in case there is at least ONE variable declaration with let or const inside the braces, since ONLY THOSE 2 create a "different" block scope than the functions, right? Thanks in advance

Comment: Or by default all code between braces (any block of code) already has its own Lexical Environment?@Felix Kling

Comment: Here is a link to the current spec: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation , but even in the part that I quoted you can see that step 2 always creates a new environment. Having said that, since the effect of having a separate environment is not visible if you don't have blocks scope declarations, it could be totally possible that engines avoid creating an additional environment in that case.

Comment: Genius @Felix Kling, now it makes sense and I understand it. Thank you very much + 1 and marked as helpful reply